# SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data"

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

On sending an HTTP DELETE request from my Angular front-end to my Node back-end, the following error is thrown:

[image: Syntax Error]

However the DELETE request still gets processed and the object deleted.

Here's my delete function in Angular:

```js
  deleteProject(id: number) {
     this.http.delete(`projects/${id}`).subscribe(
      response => {
        this.toastr.success('Project deleted.', 'Success');
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
  }
```

And in my back-end API:

```js
function remove(req, res) {

  let query = {
    _id : req.params.id
  };

  Projeto.findById(query)
  .then(async (projeto) =>  {

    if(!projeto) {
      return res.status(404).json({error: 'not_found', message: 'This project doesn\'t exist.'});
    }

    if(projeto.project_manager.toString() != req.user._id.toString()) {
      return res.status(403).json({error: 'forbidden', message: 'You can\'t delete this project.'});
    } else {
      await Projeto.findByIdAndRemove(query);
    }


    res.status(200).send("Project deleted.");


  })
  .catch(utils.handleError(req, res));
}
```

What does that error refer to and how can I fix it?

Comment: The request is succeeding from the server's perspective (and if you look in the network tab you'll see it's 200 OK for the client, too), but Angular can't parse the response - `"Project deleted."` isn't JSON. Either make it a JSON response, or see https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data.

Comment: Thanks, I changed the response to JSON and now it's working as intended.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error in my AspNet Core Web Api backend.

When we return a value in Ok method like that:

`Ok('some message')`
it gives this error:

`JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

If we use only `Ok()` without any message, it works perfectly fine :)

Here is my working controller action method:

```
    [HttpPost("{receiverId}")]
    public ActionResult LikeUser(int userId, int receiverId)
    {
         var result = _likeRepository.LikeUser(userId, receiverId);

         if(result.IsSuccessful)
            return Ok();
        else
            return BadRequest(result.Message);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The response which you are showing convert it in JSON and then try. Since your response is not of JSON format you are getting that error.